# Get menu items as data

Tags: php, mediawiki, mustache, mediawiki-templates

I am facing an issue while creating a new MediaWiki Skin. I am following the steps mentioned at [Manual:How to make a MediaWiki skin#Rendering menus with Mustache](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_make_a_MediaWiki_skin#Rendering_menus_with_Mustache). As per documentation, for showing the menu items I am using `{{{html-items}}}`, but this returns HTML as `li` elements.

I want to use some specific classes for the menu items with the `li` and `a` tags. How can I get the individual menu items, urls as data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SkinTemplateNavigation::Universal hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SkinTemplateNavigation::Universal) to manipulate menu links (in MediaWiki 1.37+; there are different hooks in older versions).

Comment: Thanks. I want to use `SkinMustache` but `SkinTemplateNavigation::Universal ` requires `SkinTemplate`.

Comment: `SkinMustache` is a subclass of `SkinTemplate`.

Comment: Is it possible to share any example of using this hook with the `SkinMustache`? I could not find related doc about this.

Comment: It's no different from using it with any other skin. The hook doesn't need to know about the skin, and the skin doesn't need to know about the hook.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just override the `runOnSkinTemplateNavigationHooks()` method, and do the same changes there.